# Change font of \cmpd+{} in chemnum package

Tags: chemnum

I want to have my numbered compounds in bold throughout my text but I want them to have a different format when used in section headers. I tried using the command `\cmpd+[format=\normalfont]{label}` but the format option doesn't work with `\cmpd+` (or `\refcmpd`).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\slshape}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}{}

\begin{document}

    \section{Preparation of \cmpd+{compoundA}}

    We made \cmpd{compoundA}.

    \section{Preparation of \cmpd+[format=\slshape]{compoundA}}

We made \cmpd{compoundA}.

\section{Preparation of \cmpd[format=\slshape]{compoundA}}

We made \cmpd{compoundA}.

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to get the format options to work with `\cmpd+`?

As mentioned in the comments the problem arises when one wants a Table of Contents. My format style prevents me from using bold in the table of contents, yet the compound numbers should be bolded in the text. Clearly I must use `\cmpd+` to avoid numbering the compound at the beginning, but no matter what I do it does not take any format arguments.

Comment: Maybe a workaround could be to define the compounds before the section with `\cmpd*` and then use the formatted `\cmpd` in the section title (and subsequently the regular `\cmpd` in the section text)?

Comment: Well that's a smart suggestion! I guess writing your thesis burns more brain cells than I thought.  I'll leave this open just in case someone else wants to do something about it, but that's definitely a viable alternative.

Comment: @Marijn Maybe I replied to quickly. The point of using `\cmpd+` was to avoid it defining the compound in the Table of Contents, which is what I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

Well I was just reading more on the `chemnum` manual and you can go around with the `\cmpdplain` command and just format the text however you want. So instead of `\cmpd+[format=\itseries]{foo}` you can use `\textit{\cmpdplain{foo}}`. Not exactly brilliant but it works for me at least.

Comment: This is the correct solution: `\cmpdplain` is provided exactly for such purposes